# Using tags and the reuse of cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array called called `totalWins`, inside it there are arrays called `winningNumbers`. Inside it there are 70 numbers I need to display in a UITableView cell. 
I've subclassed UITaableViewCell and created some `UITextField` outlets. 
The good old fashion way doing this:

```
NSArray *winningNumbers = [[_currentSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"winningNumbers"];
cell.txtFld1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:0]];
cell.txtFld2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:1]];
....
....
```

Works great. I've tried to save up some coding time and did this: (after seting up the textfields tags of course)

```
for(int i=0;i<70;i++)
    {
        UITextField *tempField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: 777+i];

        tempField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

The problem is that because of the reuse of the cells the numbers are messed up when scrolling the table view. What's the preferred way to accomplish the above without writing `cell.txtFld1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:0]];` 70 times?

Comment: It can be helpful if you post the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 777+i]* instead *self.view*. Your's solution is ok.

Comment: changed the code to `for(int i=0;i<17;i++)
    {
        UITextField *tempField = (UITextField *)  [cell.contentView viewWithTag: 777+i] ;
        
        tempField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];
    }` But i'm still getting the same bad result

Comment: Very hard to understand where trouble, when look only to piece of code. Problem somewere outside this code. Check tag values is setted. Go through all UITextField and clear text, when you return cell for table. Maybe you use wrong limit 17, and must use 70. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but it may work:

```
for (id subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textfield = (UITextField*)subview;
        textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[winningNumbers objectAtIndex:(textfield.tag-777)]];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice solution but i'm getting the same changing \ blank text in the cells.

Comment: see my edit. this should work if your tags are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITableViewCell and make an array of UITextFields.

```
@interface YourCell: UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *textfields;
@end
```

Store references to your text fields in ivar backing up `textfields` property.

Then you can do

```
NSArray *textfields = cell.textfields;
for (int i = 0; i < textfields.count; i++)
{
    UITextfield *field = [textfields objectAtIndex:i];
    // set textfield's text
}
```

Comment: I already created a subclass of UITableViewCell. Would you mind giving me some details on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is the textfield reference? How the compiler will know what's the location of the textfield I want to enter data to?

Comment: Wait, did you make all your 70(!!) textfields in interface builder?.. I'd create and add them to cell's content view programmatically.

Comment: I've created only a few in the interface builder to test things out. The main goal is to create them programmaticaly.

Comment: well, then as you create them programmatically, add them to a mutable array and then do `_textfields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:textfieldsArray];`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all created textfields and create them each time.

```
 for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: All the textfields are on different location on the cell. How can I create them each time like that?

Comment: And what's removeFromSuperView got to do with it? Thanks

Comment: As I understand you are dynamically adding them to cell?  If no, then of course it will not help